# how can I write PL/SQL Query for defining role and grant only select access to all schemas for different users

Tags: oracle, plsql

Example includes 2 roles -

1. READ_ONLY - for select access only
2. READ_WRITE - for update, insert, delete, drop, etc.

Now I want to fire pl/sql query to -

For loop to get all schema names:
Grant select on BGREADONLY to  for User_X;

Please help with the exact piece of code..

Comment: Do you really want to loop over all schema, including built-in ones like SYS? That seems unlikely, and dangerous. What is `BGREADONLY` -  a schema? a table that exists in all schemas? your real role name? or something else? Is `User_X` the schema form the loop or a different user? If you have two roles how will you decide which role to grant to the user? Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do and why, and give examples of the actual commands you want to run inside your loop.

Comment: @AlexPoole basically I have a k8's container in which there are multiple schemas, so i need to loop over all of them and assign roles to their tables (either read-only Or write) access based on users

Comment: Just to comment, the word "query" is used for SQL `select` statements that return results, and sometimes extended (wrongly in my view) to other DML, but there is no such thing as a PL/SQL Query, because PL/SQL is a programming language and not a query language.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this procedure

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE grant_select(
    in_var_username VARCHAR2, 
    in_var_grantee VARCHAR2)
AS   
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner = in_var_username
    )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'GRANT SELECT ON '||rec.owner||'.'||rec.table_name||' TO ' || in_var_grantee || '  with grant option ';
    END LOOP;
END;


-- Call the procedure

exec grant_select('OWNER_SCHEMA','ROLE_TO_BE_GRANTED');
```

Comment: I need the loop over schema level so that I can grant access of role created (READ_ONLY and READ_WRITE) to schema's objects. Need not to pass owner_schema since we donot know in future what all owners will be added.